# What is a good web-based Grid that accepts Excel clipboard data?

Tags: excel, csv, grid, clipboard

Any good recommendations for a platform agnostic (i.e. Javascript) grid control/plugin that will accept pasted Excel data and can emit Excel-compliant clipboard data during a Copy?

I believe Excel data is formatted as CSV during "normal" clipboard operations.

---

[dhtmlxGrid](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/) looks promising, but the online demo's don't actually copy contents to my clipboard!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm currently using **dhtmlxGrid** and we have the Excel copy/paste functionality working.  dhtmlXGrid is the most full featured javascript grid package that I've found.

On their website, dhtmlXGrid claims to support [Clipboard functionality](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/docsExplorer/index.shtml?node=dhtmlxgrid&type=smpl) in the Professional version.  (However, I noticed the Sample on their site isn't working on my Firefox.  EDIT: It's probably the permissions issue that Nathan mentioned.)

In any case, we had to do some extra work to get the exact Excel copy and paste functionality we wanted.  We essentially had to override some of their functionality to get the desired behavior.  Their support was pretty good in helping us come up with a solution.

So to answer your question, you should be able to get them to support copy and paste if you purchase the Professional version.  I'm just warning you that it may take some additional work to fine tune that behavior.

Overall, I'm happy with dhtmlXGrid.  We use a lot of their features.  Their support is pretty good.  They usually take one day to respond since they are in Europe (I think).  And Javascript is by its very nature open source so I can always dive in when I need to.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but a warning: my company bought the 2007 Infragistics ASP.NET controls just for the Grid, and we regret that choice.

The quality of API is horrible (in our opinion at least), making it very hard to program against the grid (for example, inconsistent naming conventions, but this is just an inconvenience, we have complaints about the object model as well).

So I can't say that I know of a better option, I just know I will give a try to something else before paying for Infragistics products again (and the email support we got was horrible as well).

Answer (score 0):

I was wrestling with this problem several years ago (2004 I think).  We ran into the problem that Firefox doesn't allow scripts to read the clipboard by default (but you can [grant access to the clipboard](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Granting+JavaScript+access+to+the+clipboard)).

There's other ways of reading the clipboard data as well...Flash, for instance, can read the clipboard.  There's a good article on [ajaxian](http://ajaxian.com/archives/auto-copy-to-clipboard) to explain how do to this behind the scenes.

In the end, we couldn't find a web-based Grid that fit the bill, so we had to create our own in a mixture of Actionscript and Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I'd hate to be Captain Obvious here...but what about a plain old .NET Gridview control?  You can copy Excel data into it and out of it...and you can run it on any system with the .NET platform installed.

Answer (score 0):

http://dhtmlx.com/dhxdocs/doku.php?id=dhtmlxgrid:clipboard_operations